# Meteor Publications and Subscriptions group of users

Tags: javascript, meteor, subscription, meteor-publications

I want to create a game where by a group of users (any number) play in a room for a instance, and this group all get notified when something happens (by any of the users).

when you say "Publications and Subscriptions", will it work if I create random publication..

I guess what am trying to say is .. what if I have 3 different groups, and I want them all to have different interaction with db and the notification will only happen with in that group

Is meteor a good solution for this?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: I'm still trying to suss out whats the best framework to build it with and thats how I landed on meteor. Since it was my first time using it, I thought I'd ask before I dive in too deep.

Answer (score 0):

That's very doable.  One possible approach would be to use the meteor-roles plugin (https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles) and then check for the role to authorize the subscription.

Comment: I don't understand, can you please elaborate how this will be useful in this scenario for example. 3 group game

group 1 (3 players): getting notifications as they are playing the game 

group 2 (4 players): same thing 

and so on